# When calling append on stringbuilder, are we adding strings to the heap?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, stringbuilder

I am wondering about the benefits of using stringbuilder when it comes to memory usage in C#.

If you have the following scenario:

```
    var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
           strBuilder.Append(i); /// is this not calling i.ToString(); ???
           strBuilder.Append(','); /// this i character comma
           strBuilder.Append(" and "); /// this is creating a new string " and " right ?
           strBuilder.Append(','); // this is a character comma, and not a string, this is value type
        }
```

My question is the following: Each time when we call the append method, are we not creating a string that is then used from the stringBuilder, to be appended and added to the internal character array - buffer ?

I assume that whenever we append something, we are also creating the string that is to be appended and then this is sitting on the heap, waiting to become garbage collected.
Is this not a perfomance hit for the heap ?

Comment: Pull the literals outside of the loop.

Comment: The code as posted allocates 1001 objects.  When append to String instead of StringBuilder then you'll allocate 7000 objects.  Big difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> are we not creating a string that is then used from the stringBuilder, to be appended and added to the internal character array - buffer ?

In your correct example, yes. The string has to be first allocated and then added to the internal buffer. But imagine you have a class with a bunch of properties that are already instantiated and you want to concatenate them together. Using `StringBuilder` to append each one saves unnecessary allocations during concatenation.

> I assume that whenever we append something, we are also creating the string that is to be appended and then this is sitting on the heap, waiting to become garbage collected. Is this not a perfomance hit for the heap ?

That string is used internally by the builder:

```
 unsafe
 {
         fixed (char* valuePtr = value)
         fixed (char* destPtr = &chunkChars[chunkLength])
         string.wstrcpy(destPtr, valuePtr, valueLen);
  }
```

And then discarded and eligable for collection. I wouldn't call a `string` on the heap a performance hit, but it will increase the size of the heap, depending on how many allocations such as these you have.

Note that in your loop, there is no reason to allocate these strings for each iteration. Declaring them outside the loop would save you that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes true, new instances of `strings` are created every time, but the same reference of `StringBuilder` instance is used. Only setting `StringBuilder` to `null` changes the reference of `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Is comma, going to be on the stack or the heap ? I got confused here... Is there a .ToString() called on the comma as well ?

Comment: My bad. Its a method parameter and hence it will live on stack. I have edited the answer.